# Spring Boot - Correct way to map both JSP and REST URI to be handled in controller?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a problem with Spring boot 1.5.2, I also added all the dependencies for JSP so it could return from web application (war) file.

application.properties

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
```

pom.xml with JSP dependencies

```
<!-- JSTL for JSP -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Need this to compile JSP -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Need this to compile JSP,
    tomcat-embed-jasper version is not working, no idea why -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
        <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
        <version>4.6.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

And I have a simple controller like this

```
@Controller
public class ClassController {
    @RequestMapping("/**")
    public String handle(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
       // This one can handle any rest URIs, e.g: localhost:8080/application/abc, localhost:8080/application/abc/12/asdasd/3123,...
    }
}
```

However, I could not return index.jsp from localhost:8080/application/index.jsp as it will not invoke the method handle, but return

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Mon Oct 02 10:20:39 CEST 2017
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
```

What is the proper configuration, so I could direct request with .jsp (e.g: http://localhost:8080/application/index.jsp) to jsp file (WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp), and REST uri (http://localhost:8080/application/132/21321312/324) to the handle method?

Comment: What do you return in the controller method? To see the page you should return just string "index". Also paste your servlet configuration as it is unclear what mapping do you define for DispatcherServlet (context path/servlet path)

Comment: I just return "" in the handle() method. I don't have servlet configuration ? as I'm using Spring boot.

Comment: try to return "application/index" and in browser use `http://localhost:8080/application/index.jsp`

Comment: I added the return in handle() method and tried the uri to jsp file, but still returns 404 not found.

Comment: Ok, are you able to see incoming requests in console log? What are the uri's?

Comment: The log does not really help, it just says it could not find the page, you can see here https://pastebin.com/8C1HcbPR

Comment: Could you share you project?

Comment: @DmitrySenkovich I did not do much, you could have the project from László which he tried to build from my question. https://github.com/springuni/springuni-stackoverflow/tree/master/question-46521912

I quoted my comment "What I wanted is: I could connect to both URI (1 with JSP: localhost:8080/application/index.jsp) and 1 with a random REST URI (which will not have anything to do with index.jsp, e.g: localhost:8080/application/12/3123). Try to think like with index.jsp it will return Hello László in a html page and for the REST URI handle() it will just a result of 1 + 2 = 3 in string."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155764/discussion-between-bng-rikimaru-and-dmitry-senkovich).

Comment: ok, I'll get back in several hours, I'm at work now

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem with using a servlet filter to forward requests containing .jsp to the corresponding files inside /WEB-INF/jsp. Other requests will go to the handle() method inside the controller.

```
 @WebFilter(urlPatterns = "/*")
public class SecoreFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        if (!request.getRequestURI().endsWith(".jsp")) {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        } else {
            String jspFile = new File(request.getRequestURI()).getName();
            // e.g: /application/3223/234234/2342323/browse.jsp
            String uri = request.getRequestURI();
            // extract the jsp file from uri
            uri = uri.substring(0, uri.length() - jspFile.length());
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = req.getServletContext()
                    .getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsp/" + jspFile);
            req.setAttribute("uri", uri);
            dispatcher.forward(req, response);
            // chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've rebuilt your project based on your description and found two issues.

- **tomcat-embed-jasper** needs to be a compile time dependency and you don't need the Eclipse compiler
- In the controller (**ClassController**), you have to return the name of the view, which is **index** in your case.

You can find a working example here: https://github.com/springuni/springuni-stackoverflow/tree/master/question-46521912

What it does is that it redirects any given request (/application/132/21321312/324) to **index.jsp**. In the JSP the path of the request is written to the output for demonstrating that the redirection actually came from the controller.

Let me know if it worked for you!

Cheers,
László

Comment: thanks László for your helpful support, but it seems it is more complicated than what you built. What I wanted is: I could connect to both URI (1 with JSP: localhost:8080/application/index.jsp) and 1 with a random REST URI (which will not have anything to do with index.jsp, e.g: localhost:8080/application/12/3123). Try to think like with index.jsp it will return Hello László in a html page and for the REST URI handle() it will just a result of 1 + 2 = 3 in string.

Comment: Okay, now I understand better what you want to achieve. If you want to access the JSP directly, then you have to put it outside of `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF`. I've added `index2.jsp` as an example for that. Altought that approach would break the MVC paradigm, so I wouldn't recommend.
The other way is to define separate controller method(s) for working with JSPs and working with other requests.
In the modified example, I added method `index()` to do the former and altered method `handle()` for your example above to do the latter.

Comment: sorry to ask this question, "@RequestMapping("/application/index.jsp")" did you test it? because I could not go to the method to handle this request in my case before, so I need to ask. Also "@RequestMapping("/application/{arg1}/{arg2}")" is not what I wanted, 1 +  2 = 3 is just example and here I wanted to have a random URI (e.g: /application/213213/213asdasd/2132132132/1321321) to handle.

Comment: I should have known, that it's not going to work that way, sorry about that. I did a bit of refactoring.
Path `/application/index.jsp` is served directly by Tomcat and addresses `src/main/webapp/application/index.jsp`, as I mentioned before this solution breaks the MVC pattern.
Path `/application/index.do` is served by controller method `index()`, which then re-routes the request to JSP `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp`. This is the standard Spring MVC way.
Path `/application/**` is now served by controller method `handle()` and you can use whatever url suffix you would like.

Comment: although, I could not test your project but thanks for your effort.